# drupal rotating banner duplicating text

Tags: drupal-7, content-management-system

I am editing a drupal site. Problem is, once I insert an image in the slider inside the rotating banner and type the banner text, the banner text duplicates itself like 7 times. What could be the problem? The configuration theme is 7. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the banner created using the "views" drupal module by any chance?

Sometimes the groupings on them get messed up.  It might be that, or it could be a templating issue.  It's difficult to tell without either seeing an example, or seeing some code.

In all honesty, it could be a number of things.  Are you able to provide further information?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is created in the 'blocks' module. I guess its a template issue. Kindly visit http://4ntesacco.co.ke/ and see what am talking about. With regards, Silas

Comment: That's a problem with your plugin which is rotating the banner.  Notice that when it first loads, there is one slide showing.

When the second slide shows, the first should hide.  What actually happens is that both show.  You'll need to sort that out first.

I think when you sort that, you'll be closer, but I suspect you'll then see a different issue, but one thing at a time.